# Hilbert Function of two non-intersecting lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-geometry

We are asked to compute the Hilbert function of two non-intersecting lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$. I'm not sure where to start here. Any hints or even a sketch of a full solution would be greatly appreciated.

In general, how do we go about finding the Hilbert function of lines in the projective space of arbitrary dimensions? I was thinking about finding an ideal that generates the lines and then computing the function normally by counting the number of monomials in the coordinate ring but not in the ideal. What is the most efficient way to do this? Let me know if you need any more context.

Comment: You start with the computation of the Hilbert function of a single line. For this you must understand how the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(n)$ on $\mathbb{P}^3$ restricts to the line, and what is the cohomology of this restriction.

Comment: @Sasha I am working on Gathmann's text. More specifically, 2014 edition chapter 12 exercise 4. We have not worked with cohomology and line bundles. Is it safe to say we can compute the Hilbert functions of  individual lines respectively and then add them together?

Comment: I don't know this book, so I am not sure what the author had in mind. But definitely the Hilbert function of a disjoint union is equal to the sum of Hilbert functions.

Answer (score 1):

Take the two lines to be $ x=y=0 $ and $ z=w=0 $ WLOG. (The general case is exactly the same) Then the ideal of the two lines is $ J = (xz,xw,yz,yw) $ and now let's count monomials of degree $ d $ in $ \mathbb{C}[x,y,z,w]/J $ as you suggested. The only surviving monomials are $ x^d, y^d, z^d, w^d $ and $ x^ay^b, z^aw^b $ with $ a+b = d, a,b > 0 $. This is a count of $ 4 + 2(d-1) = 2d+2 $. So the Hilbert polynomial is $ p(t) = 2(t + 1) $ which is the right answer because it's twice the Hilbert polynomial of a line.